# Import-Module in the Docker PowerShell image

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile

I'm building a Docker image based from `microsoft/powershell:ubuntu16.04`.  It builds properly without any error, however when I go to use it it doesn't have the imported module that I stated in the Dockerfile (which is a psd1 file from a GitHub repo cloned in the image.

I tried with a simple import of Microsoft's powershell management as well (seen below), and it also doesn't get imported.  I ran the image interactively and the commands one by one and everything imported fine, so I don't know why it doesn't work through the Dockerfile build itself.

```
FROM microsoft/powershell:ubuntu16.04
WORKDIR /workdir

RUN pwsh -command "Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management"

CMD [ "pwsh", "-Command", "Get-Module" ]
```

Example psd1 file

```
FROM microsoft/powershell:ubuntu16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git -y
RUN git clone https://github.com/DTW-DanWard/PowerShell-Beautifier.git
RUN cp -a PowerShell-Beautifier/src/. /opt/microsoft/powershell/6.0.0-rc/Modules

ENTRYPOINT [ "pwsh", "-c" ]
CMD [ "Get-Help", "Edit-DTWBeautifyScript" ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it happens in a wrong "context". For this to work the way you want it to work you need to use both these commands in 1 powershell session:

```
pwsh -command "Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management; Get-Module"
```

else it creates a layer where it ran that command, but when powershell stops all the imports are gone (and when the layer is done, it shuts down the container, so it doesnt preserve session state, only os state).

My dockerfile (working example):

```
FROM microsoft/powershell:ubuntu16.04
RUN pwsh -c "Install-Module AzureRM.netcore -Force"

CMD [ "pwsh" ]
```

Comment: I think I understand your explanation, but not your suggestion.  What does adding `Get-Module` to the end of that RUN statement do differently exactly?  I still tried it and didn't get the results I wanted.  I basically want the imported module to be available inside the image so when it's run as a container, I can use the commands from that imported module.

Comment: this is supposed to be in the `CMD` not in the `RUN`

Comment: OK, got it.  So when I replace `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` with the psd1 file I want to import, it says `[: missing]`.  When I run it manually via `docker run -it [image name] Import-Module .\[module file name].psd1`, it says the specified module was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.  I know it's there because I ran the intermediate image that loads the files and listed the files, and they are there.

Comment: My assumption is it's looking for it in my local, not in the image/container which is what it should be doing, but don't know how to do that.

Comment: no, that is not possible. honestly, your whole approach is wrong, you should just use any folder under psmodulepath. you wont even need to load it in this case, it will get loaded automatically

Comment: Nope doesn't get loaded.  I moved the files to `/opt/microsoft/powershell/6.0.0-rc/Modules` within the image, but still get errors saying it can't find it.  When I run the image interactively, it's not listed under Get-Modules.  When I go to to that directory directly and manually import, it shows up.  That path is under $env:PSModulePath

Comment: I cannot replicate your findings. I've downloaded and put a module into that folder and it correctly finds it and imports it "on the fly". I'm using the same base image you are using in your dockerfile

Comment: Can you provide an example dockerfile where you copy into the image (or git clone in the image) a module psd1 file and move to that folder?  I've updated my question with what I have which:  installs git, clones the repo, and moves the psd1 files to that directory.

Comment: I believe the explanation of why this answer is correct, according to my situation at least, is the `-Force` part. When installing a module Powershell asks you for a confirmation, which is not shown when is part of a Dockerfile RUN command. Adding `-Force` forces the import to happen without a prompt. I just ran the RUN command with that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I found an alternative: By finding out the `$env:PSModulePath` of the base image, you can use `Save-Module` to install the module into a folder that's known to PowerShell.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-ubuntu-jammy

WORKDIR /app

RUN pwsh -c "Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -InstallationPolicy Trusted; Find-Module -Name 'ExchangeOnlineManagement' -Repository 'PSGallery' | Save-Module -Path '/opt/microsoft/powershell/7-lts/Modules'; Find-Module -Name 'Pode' -Repository 'PSGallery' | Save-Module -Path '/opt/microsoft/powershell/7-lts/Modules';"
COPY script.ps1 .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "pwsh", "-c", "./script.ps1" ]
```